# Without @EnableWebMvc the application (not spring-boot) still works, so where is this annotation for?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple spring mvc application. I deploy it in tomcat, it is not a spring-boot application. I use spring version 5.3.21,

I was wondering what @EnableWebMvc does. I removed it, but the application still works. I use `@RequestMapping("/")` which should not work without @EnableWebMvc, I read. Or are there other things which does not work without @EnableWebMvc?

1.

```
package spittr.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "spittr" })
public class RootConfig {
}
```

2. 

```
package spittr.config;


import spittr.web.WebConfig;

public class SpitterWebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

3. 

```
package spittr.web;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping(method = GET)
  public String home(Model model) {
    return "home";
  }
}
```

4. 

```
package spittr.web;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

5. 

$ vi src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Spitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          type="text/css" 
          href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" >
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Spitter</h1>

    <a href="<c:url value="/spittles" />">Spittles</a> | 
    <a href="<c:url value="/spitter/register" />">Register</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When trying to build a Spring-based project, we need to manually set up a message converter to convert messages or a view resolver to render the view. However, making the same settings every time a project was created was a waste of money for developers, so Spring began providing a function to automate settings based on the latest strategies for these areas, which is @Enable~ This is an annotation that starts with.

By attaching the starting annotation to the configuration class with @Configuration, related functions can be conveniently provided. Among them, @EnableWebMvc is the representative one. By attaching it, the latest strategy beans related to the web provided by Spring are registered.

In fact, if you look for the beans registered when @EnableWebMvc is set and when it is not, you will be able to see a difference.